# PATCH_SUPEE-6788 not installed correctly

Tags: magento-1.8, patches, supee-6788

I am trying to install PATCH_SUPEE-6788 for my magento installation ver. 1.8.1.0 
like below :

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-59-27.sh
```

But i get below error:

[image]

It says Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!

But in the file `/app/etc/applied.patches.list` the patch 6482 is not present.

Can anyone let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have applied all the previous patches then check if your magento installation has .htaccess and .htaccess.sample file present in the root directory

Comment: `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.sample` both are present

Answer (score 3):

**Please try below solution,hope it's helpful for you.**

> Install SUPEE-6788 without SSH
>
> https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6788-without-ssh/
>
> Before applying this patch, make sure to apply all previous patches or not via below URL:-
>
> https://www.magereport.com
>
> All following previous patches:-
>
> http://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6482-without-ssh/
>
> http://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6285-without-ssh/
>
> https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-5994-without-ssh/
>
> http://magentary.com/kb/apply-supee-5344-and-supee-1533-without-ssh/

Comment: thank for explain in details, it's very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

First check if old patches installed or not.6788 patch not installing means if someone uploaded file we are unable to find `/app/etc/applied.patches.list`
so download patch file compare one or two.Then install